# How do I add a downloaded custom font to a navigationBar title in Swift?

Tags: swift, fonts, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I downloaded a cool font, and want to use it as the nav bar title for my app, but can't seem to get the app to recognize/display it. An exception is thrown every run attempt. Here are the steps I took.

1. I moved the `myCustomFont.ttf` file into the project as I do other supporting files (images, etc.)
2. Updated my `info.plist` file by adding `Font provided by application`, and adding the name of the file to the array
3. Then, I added the following code to `AppDelegate.swift`

```
// Navigation bar customization
let navigationController = window!.rootViewController as UINavigationController

navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : (UIFont(name: "myCustomFont", size: 10))!]
```

The above code works if I replace `myfont` with something standard like `Times New Roman` or `Arial`.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In Xcode open the project target and make sure that the font file is included in the Copy Bundle Resources in the Build Phases section.

Comment: The font file is definitely included in the Copy Bundle Resources in the Build Phases section. So, there must be an issue with my code or something. Thanks for the response though man.

Comment: AHAHAHHAAAA! Figured it out! I had to right click on the .ttf file, Get Info, and copy the FULL NAME (which is different than the filename). I used the FULL NAME string in the code and BOOM it worked! I'm a genius! Lol :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure your font is in Bundle Resources. For some reason Xcode it is not importing custom font properly most of the time:

[image]

and try this in the AppDelegate

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "JennaSue", size: 20)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : uicolorFromHex(0x5C8CA7)]
```